# How to handle Null response in Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I am facing this issue in many places because I don't have any idea about handling null in retrofit.

For Example:

```
 1.  "name": "Deadpool 2 Trailer",
    "full_movie": "DEADPOOL_2_Teaser_Trailer__2018_.mp4",
    "story": "",
    "genre": null,
    "censor_rating": "&nbsp;",
    "release_date": null,

2.     "name": "Den utrolige historie om den kæmpestore pære",
        "full_movie": "Den_utrolige_historie_om_den_k__mpestore_p__re.mp4",
        "story": "XYZ"
        "genre": [
            "Animation"
        ],
        "censor_rating": "&nbsp;",
        "release_date": "2018-03-05",
        "content_types_id": "1",
```

As you can see genre is null in first case and in second case it is array type. As my pojo class is of course made on the 2nd type. So when I am getting 1st type response from the server, my application gets stops totally. Debug stuck at one place and nothing happens. Though Application is not crashing. How to handle this ?

Comment: Not enough info to answer, please post some code

Comment: just wanna know to handle this null response?

Comment: description is to poor. but i can suggest you to use @Nullable annotation to fields that could be null. And you can provide some default value in your getter if you wanna avoid null check in you code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if key is null by using this code

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("genre"))
{
// handle null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when getting response that store in into your pojo class.
and when set data that time check like

```
     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(pojoclassObject.getStory())){

         }
```